# Amazon S3 Bucket Failed upload

Tags: wagtail

I am just working on my very first wagtail site and I am looking at using Amazon S3 to serve the media files. I have been following the steps from [this very helpful guide](https://wagtail.io/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/) but on uploading media files in development testing I am hit with the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutObject operation: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

I have done some searching online as well as stackoverflow but I am just not understanding the issue. My bucket is located in London.

Can anyone shed some light on the fix for this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it it looks like the API I was interacting with was django-storage not really boto3.

By adding

> AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'

Allowed me to use S3 bucket for media. More info [here](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/28).

Comment: Thanks, This was helpful.